# Can't restart the network service on CentOS

Tags: networking, centos, networkmanager

I am trying to restart my network on my CentOS server on a Raspberry PI 3 with

> systemctl restart network

However, I am getting this

> Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl
>   -xe" for details.

```
[root@rpiserver ~]# systemctl status network.service
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-07-02 21:08:50 UTC; 2min 46s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1002 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=6)

Jul 02 21:08:50 rpiserver systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Jul 02 21:08:50 rpiserver systemd[1]: network.service: control process exit...=6
Jul 02 21:08:50 rpiserver systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down ne...g.
Jul 02 21:08:50 rpiserver systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Jul 02 21:08:50 rpiserver systemd[1]: network.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

This is my ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.1.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset the present configurations in your eth0 network card

```
ip addr flush eth0
```

And try again

```
systemctl restart networking
```

---

For future posts, use the follow command for show all logs

*Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.*

```
systemctl status networking -l
```